# How to connect 2 lightsail instances in different regions with each other so data can transmit between them?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I'm new to AWS and have a Lightsail instance in a specific region. I've made an other lightsail instance in a different region and want them to communicate with each other(transmit data and whatnot). The AWS faqs state :

"Each Lightsail instance automatically gets a private IP address and a public IP address. You can use the private IP to transmit data between Lightsail instances and AWS resources privately, for free. "

I want to know how this is possible and where do i start.

Answer (score 0):

Different regions so that it's in different VPCs.

You can search AWS VPC peering to connect 2 VPC and can communicate with the private IP address

Comment: https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/lightsail-how-to-set-up-vpc-peering-with-aws-resources 
I think all you need is in this link

Comment: Can instances communicate in the same region but different Availability Zones via private IP? If yes, please point me to the docs.

Comment: Bro does it worked, I am searching for same, if you found solution could you please share here

Answer (score 0):

One option to enable private connectivity between lightsail instances in different regions (or accounts) is to create a virtual software overlay network between the hosts.

Worth investigating [enclave.io](https://enclave.io), [tailscale.com](https://tailscale.com) and [zerotier.com](https://zerotier.com).

These are nice options because they don't require any special configuration/costs of the AWS network (or open public ports). You just install an agent on each instance you
wish to connect, define your "virtual" network, and away you go.  Each system gets a private virtual IP address they can use to communicate.

They don't require you to run any VPN servers or other infrastructure, and they're point-to-point, so your data doesn't flow through anyone else's servers.

Full disclosure: I work for enclave.io